# Android bluetooth get connected devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-profile

How can I get a list of all connected bluetooth devices for Android regardless of profile?

Alternatively, I see that you can get all connected devices for a specific profile via [BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#getConnectedDevices(int)).

And I guess I could see which devices are connected by listening for connections/disconnections via [ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)/[ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)*...seems error prone*.

But I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to get the list of all connected bluetooth devices.

Comment: you're right in that just listening to acl connected / disconnect is problematic because it can occur while your app is not running or listening for the broadcasts

Comment: have you found the solution @Steven Wexier

Comment: I found a solution and it works on android 10
[code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308359/12119438)

Answer (score 5):

To see a complete list, this is a 2-step operation:

1. get list of currently paired devices
2. scan for, or discover, all others in range

To get a list of, and iterate, the currently paired devices:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
    for (BluetoothDevice d: pairedDevices) {
        String deviceName = d.getName();
        String macAddress = d.getAddress();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "paired device: " + deviceName + " at " + macAddress);
        // do what you need/want this these list items
    }
}
```

Discovery is a little bit more of a complex operation.  To do this, you'll need to tell the BluetoothAdapter to start scanning/discovering.  As it finds things, it sends out Intents that you'll need to receive with a BroadcastReceiver.

First, we'll set up the receiver:

```
private void setupBluetoothReceiver()
{
    BroadcastRecevier btReceiver = new BroadcastReciver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            handleBtEvent(context, intent);
        }
    };
    IntentFilter eventFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    // this is not strictly necessary, but you may wish
    //  to know when the discovery cycle is done as well
    eventFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    myContext.registerReceiver(btReceiver, eventFilter);
}

private void handleBtEvent(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "action received: " + action);

    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "found device: " + device.getName());
    } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "discovery complete");
    }
}
```

Now all that is left is to tell the BluetoothAdapter to start scanning:

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
// if already scanning ... cancel
if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}

btAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

Comment: It would be most helpful if the down-voting readers would take the time to comment on what it is they don't like.  The above code is exactly what I'm doing to achieve the OP's objective ... and it appears to be working as expected, at least for me.

Comment: You don't need to pair a Bluetooth Low Energy device to connect to it. And ´getBondedDevices()´ would not return connected BLE devices. Therefore your code is not really doing what is requested.

Comment: FYI, these codes only applicable for Bluetooth Classic devices. They aren't for BLE devices. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth

Comment: It can get list of paired devices but I don't know which one is connected

Comment: Can we get only currently Bluetooth connected device name ?

Comment: getBondedDevices() gives you currently paired devices, not currently connected devices. There can be paired devices that are not connected, and there can be connected devices that are not paired.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to get your connected devices like the following:

1. paired device

   ```
   val btManager = baseContext.getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
   val pairedDevices = btManager.adapter.bondedDevices

   if (pairedDevices.size > 0) {

       for (device in pairedDevices) {
           val deviceName = device.name
           val macAddress = device.address
           val aliasing = device.alias

           Log.i(
               " pairedDevices ",
               "paired device: $deviceName at $macAddress + $aliasing " + isConnected(device)
           )
       }
   }
   ```
2. check whatever is connected or no.

To check if the paired Device is connected or no, u need to use this method:

```
private fun isConnected(device: BluetoothDevice): Boolean {
    return try {
        val m: Method = device.javaClass.getMethod("isConnected")
        m.invoke(device) as Boolean
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw IllegalStateException(e)
    }
}
```

ref [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java).

Comment: This is for bonded devices, not connected devices. i.e. pair a device and disconnect. it'll still be in the bonded devices.

Comment: After getting the bounded devices, u are going to check if this bounded device is connected or not. 

This is the simplest way to get the connected devices on your Android

Comment: How about `getProfileProxy`?

Comment: @AbdallahAbuSalah there is a difference between connected and bonding. A device that is connected is not necessarily bonded so you will miss devices.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you get "connected" devices, not just paired devices. No need to check further state of it.

```
val btManager = view.getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
val connectedDevices = btManager.getConnectedDevices(GATT)
```

Comment: This is for gatt connection.

Comment: Agree with @Hiro, This does not show connected devices