# How to get name of the connected Bluetooth device on android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to get the name of the device that is connected to the Android phone running android Oreo.

I was searching for an answer for the past two days, and none of them worked. suggestions mostly returning `ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth` error

The question is, is there any way to make Query that returns the connected Bluetooth device?

These are the links and suggestion which not working:

- [IOException: read failed, socket might closed - Bluetooth on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3)
- [In Android, how to get the profile of a connected bluetooth device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556797/in-android-how-to-get-the-profile-of-a-connected-bluetooth-device)
- [list connected bluetooth devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932228/list-connected-bluetooth-devices)

I can get information about the device that is previously paired and trying to make a connection or a device trying to pair to the device. what I want is the name or the connection state of the currently paired and connected device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is the answer :

```
String name;
String address;
String threadName;
public void checkConnected()
{

       BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(this, serviceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
}

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener serviceListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy)
    {

        for (BluetoothDevice device : proxy.getConnectedDevices())
        {
            name = device.getName();
            address = device.getAddress();
            threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name+" " + address+ threadName,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txtName.setText(name + " " + address);
            Log.i("onServiceConnected", "|" + device.getName() + " | " + device.getAddress() + " | " + proxy.getConnectionState(device) + "(connected = "
                    + BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED + ")");
        }

        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().closeProfileProxy(profile, proxy);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("abc", uuid);          
BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothSocket.getRemoteDevice();
String deviceName = device.getName();
```

Comment: looks like the code stock when it get to this line `BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();`

Comment: yes, it's waiting for new incoming bluetooth connection request

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices

Check out the sections "Querying paired devices" and "Discovering devices". Especially the call to device.getName()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I want is to get the connection status of the currently paired and connected Bluetooth device . No the ones that are trying to connect. For that situation I preferred to use broadcast Listers

Comment: And about the link you mentioned, BluetoothDevice class doesn't provide a function to make a query of paired devices connection state

Comment: Thank you very much